# why pointer-events: none; and touch-action: none; doesnt work in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code but the `pointer-events: none; touch-action: none;` do not work. I can click on the element under (the blue element) when the red button is clearly showing and it is over it!!

```js
  // JavaScript click function
    function handleClick() {
        alert("Element clicked!");
    }

    // Get the element by its ID
    var clickableElement = document.getElementById("myClickableElement");

    // Attach the click event listener
    clickableElement.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```css
.cover {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fade-out 4s /*infinite*/;
    z-index: 9999999999999;
   pointer-events: none;
   touch-action: none;
   visibility: hidden;

}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0%, 85% {
        opacity: 1;
     visibility: visible;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    
    }
}

.othestuff{
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    z-index: 999;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
</div>

<div class="othestuff" id="myClickableElement">

</div>
```

what am I doing wrong? am I missing something?

Comment: You've misunderstood the purpose of pointer-events rules.  This is exactly what 'pointer-events: none' is for; it removes the ability to catch mouse events from *that element*, allowing the click events to fall through to elements "behind" that one.   If you want the overlay to catch the clicks, `pointer-events: none` on it is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: If you want the blue element to not be clickable, put `pointer-events: none` on the blue element, not on the element overlaying it.